# MATLAB .fig to a mesh file?

Tags: matlab, 3d, mesh

I'm not sure if this is possible, but given the following in MATLAB:

```
a = [1 2 3]
b = [3 1 2]

G = Graph(a,b)

x = [0 0 1]
y = [0 1 0]
z = [1 0 0]

plot(G, 'XData', x, 'YData', y, 'ZData', z)
```

The plot can be outputted into a .fig file. The goal would be to turn this into any sort of mesh file, such that it outputs into just nodes and edges, but no surfaces (or create small, cylindrical surfaces as edges).

Comment: there's something at the MATLAB file exchange regarding this: [stlwrite](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20922-stlwrite-write-ascii-or-binary-stl-files). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @gehbiszumeis this looks like what I'm working for, but I'm not sure how to input a graph into this.

Comment: A mesh is required to have faces, so you're going to have to manually create cylindrical (or rectangular) surfaces and then rotate and stretch them to line up with the edges defined in your graph